# Importance of Guru

Tags: krishna, guru

The scriptures tell us that the only way to God is through the mercy of a Guru. Is having a Guru and being tutored by him important and required to get liberation from the material world? Is God only gracious to those souls who are under the tutelage of a Guru or one who have been initiated by a Guru into a particular sampradaya? 
According to Srimad Bhagavatam and the Brihad Bhagavatamrita by Srila Sanatana Goswami, the Gopis of Vrndavan are the greatest of all Krsna's devotees and are eternally participating in the divine pastimes of Krsna in Golok Vrndavan. But the Gopis neither had any Guru nor belonged to any particular sampradaya nor did they chant any mantra! Nonetheless they are Lord Krsna's closest associates who partake in His confidential Maha Raas pastimes.
How did the Gopis of Vrndavan who were but illiterate cow-herding villagers who had no formal religious education under the guidance of a Guru attained liberation and received God's love, grace and association which even lord Brahma and lord Siva find difficult?

Comment: No you do not need a guru. You can ask the trimurti to guide you as a guru.

Comment: Did not the gopis have Krishna Himself as their guru? Is it not up to the Lord's Own sweet will who His grace descends upon? For those who are not blessed with Sri Krishna as their daily companion, a guru is necessary.